# jquery, javascript object insert in cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery

whats wrong with my code, why cookie is empty?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    personObj = new Object();
    personObj.firstname="John";
    personObj.lastname="Doe";

    $.cookie("test_cookie", personObj, { path: "/"}, { expires: 1 });       
});
</script>
```

I need get this result:

```
test_cookie => array(personObj => array( firstname=>"John",  lastname=>"Doe"))
```

thanks ;)

Comment: Cookie plugin: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/blob/master/jquery.cookie.js#L63

Answer (score 3):

Afaik, there is no build in `cookie` function in jQuery so you must use a plugin. You are using [this one](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) which does not accept objects as values ([check the source code](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/blob/master/jquery.cookie.js#L63)):

Serialize the object to a string first:

```
$.cookie("test_cookie", JSON.stringify(personObj), { path: "/", expires: 1 });
```

On the server side (looks like PHP):

```
$person = json_decode($_COOKIE['test_cookie'], true);
```

---

Also, a better way to create plain objects is:

```
var personObj = {
    firstname: "John",
    lastname: "Doe"
};
```

and don't forget `var` before `personObj` (otherwise you create a global variable).

Comment: Thanks, but how in objeck insert objeckt?

Comment: @lolalola: You mean `personObj = {name: 'foo', someObject: {name: 'bar'}}` ? If not, you have to clarify your question.